# Disambiguation of [mse] tag

Tags: support, tag-disambiguation

[@cricket_007](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/cricket-007) advised at [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41776280/why-call-endofstream-before-play-in-mse?noredirect=1#comment70743975_41776280) at [Why call 'endOfStream' before play in MSE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41776280/why-call-endofstream-before-play-in-mse) that [`mse`](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/31877) means

> MSE stands for mean-squred error. It's a measurement of an empirical
>   loss in certain mathematical models, specially regression models.

MSE can also reference

[Media Source Extensions™](https://www.w3.org/TR/media-source); see also [MSE-REGISTRY](https://www.w3.org/TR/mse-byte-stream-format-registry/).

Users at Stack Overflow have apparently found a way for harmonious use of the tag [mse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mse) for both of the above definitions.

Should a new tag be created for disambiguation?

Comment: MSE also means Meta Stack Exchange...

Comment: @Braiam Yes, posted at meta stackexchange first, was advised the Question was off-topic for MSE. The users seem to be able to differentiate the subject matter within Question body. Perhaps disambiguation and new tag is not necessary.